# Does every regular expression describe only 1 language?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

If we have a regular expression $R$, will $R$ describe only regular language $L$, but that language $L$ can have multiple different regular expressions such as $Q,W,A,S,D \ etc..$ describing it

Also, $R$ can be equivalent, in terms of describing $L$, to infinite regular expressions including $ Q,W,A,S,D \ etec..$

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: How could a regular expression describe more than one language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $e$ is a regular expression such that $\mathcal{L}(e) = L$, then so is $e+\emptyset$, $e+\emptyset+\emptyset$, …

Comment: Yes!! One more doubt regarding what you said ~ it's also possible to have two completely different regular expressions describing a regular language correct? Asking because different methods like arden's or state elimination method produce different expressions. Even in Arden's theorem, sometimes the order in which we substitute leads to different expressions. According to me, it's possible

Comment: "it's also possible to have two completely different regular expressions describing a regular language correct?" > that's litteraly what my answer prove.

Comment: Oh my bad, i thought your gave an example for the "a regular expression is equal to inifinite other regular expressions". Thank You! and sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: A regular expression is a sequence of symbols. Two regular expressions with different sequences of symbols cannot be equal. However, the language they describe can be equal. That's why I am talking about the **interpretation** of a regular expression, denoted $\mathcal{L}(e)$. Though one can sometimes write something like $(a+b)^* = (a^*b^*)^*$, this is an abuse of notation that, in reality, means $\mathcal{L}((a+b)^*) = \mathcal{L}((a^*b^*)^*)$.